# Запрос данных через fetch, ожидание обработки и использование в JS openLayers для карт OSM

Tags: javascript, fetch, openstreetmap

У меня есть массив получаю его по fetch. Далее я его использую для отрисовки иконок на карте OSM через open layers скрипт. Получается так что функции у меня уже выполняются, иконок не появляется так как им нужны данные из массива который еще не обработан получается вот суть проблемы.

Массив:

```
var pointsStation = [];
async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('getdata.php');
        const data = await response.json();

        data.forEach(point => {
            var newPoint = {
                id: point.idstation,
                name: point.stationName,
                timearr: point.timearrft,
                timesend: point.timesendft,
                cords: [point.longitude, point.latitude]
            };
            pointsStation.push(newPoint);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
}
fetchData();
```

Далее этот массив использую в функциях вида:

```
function addMarkerStations() {
    for (var j = 0; j < pointsStation.length; j++) {
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(pointsStation[j].cords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name: pointsStation[j].name,
            timearr: pointsStation[j].timearr,
            timedep: pointsStation[j].timedep,
            id: 'station-' + pointsStation[j].id
        });
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                scale: 0.28,
                opacity: 0.8,
                src: "https://school.stnorbert.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/bus-stop-filled-100.png"
            })
        });
        iconFeature.setStyle([iconStyle]);
        iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
    }
    iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: iconFeatures});
}
```

Я понимаю что нужно вроде как через async/wait делать, я переписал под этот синтаксис код, но дальше не понимаю когда лучше вызывать функции по отрисовке. И не хотелось бы сильно затрагивать эти функции по отрисовке, иначе начинаются проблемы с главным скприптом карты OSM.

Comment: Как вариант: `fetchData().then(addMarkerStations)`

Comment: Это добавлять сразу после обработки запроса? Я попробовал. Но появляются ошибки от главного скрипта карты.

Comment: Ну да. Как только fetchData отработает, запустит ваш addMarker. Я бы еще и массив внутрь fetchData положил и его возращал бы, передавая в addMarker

Comment: А можете указать, не понял пока

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблему разрешил, все функции для отрисовки карты сделал сразу после обработки запроса, все оказалось проще:

```
 fetch('getdata.php')
            .then(async response => await response.json())
            .then(async data =>
```

....в этом then после цикла